# Convert the int into double inside of a constructor

Tags: java, casting, double, typeconverter

I have a constructor whose parameters are both `int`: `Berries( int a, int b )` and I need to put a `double` in the place of "a" in the code: `Berries( 23.45, 6)`. I tried with cast, but it does not work.

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Show us how you tried to cast it and what you mean by "does not work".

Comment: a double in the constructor can take both an int and a double, while an int can only take a double. Consider changing your constructor parameter types

Comment: Providing your code and any specific error message you're getting will increase your chances of getting an answer

Comment: Where is the code showing where you tried to cast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the ugly solution

new Berries((new Double(23.45)).intValue(),6)

Comment: If you're going to answer, why not answer with the non-ugly solution?

Answer (score 0):

Typecasting can be used to change the compile-time type of an expression. For example, a value of type double can be cast into a value of type integer. This is achieved by putting the desired type in parenthesis as in 'new Berries((int)23.45, 6)'. A working example of typecasting the arguments of a constructor is shown below.

```
public class Berries {
  Berries(int a, int b) {
    System.out.println("a = " + a + " b = " + b);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args ) {
    Berries b = new Berries((int)23.45, 6);
  }
}
```

The output of running this is:

```
$ java Berries
a = 23 b = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why would you ever need that?

Either change the constructor to accept double, or send an integer value as an argument